# "And" and "Or" operators in conditionals in C

Tags: c, optimization, logical-operators, evaluation, logical-and

I always wondered about something and couldn`t find an answer somewhere else. If I have this piece of code:

```
if ((cond1) &&(cond2) && (cond 3) && (cond 4))
 {
       // do something
 }
```

Let`s say the first condition is false, then my program will verify the other conditions too, or just skip verifying them?

But if I have

```
if ((cond1) ||(cond2) || (cond 3) || (cond 4))
 {
       // do something
 }
```

and cond 1 is true, will my program go instantly on the if part or continue to verify the other conditions too?

Comment: google for "short circuit evaluation"

Comment: What did your C book or any online resource say about the `||` and `&&` operators? What was unclear?

Comment: Yes, if you have `false && ...` or `true || ...` the rest of the condition will be skipped. It's called [short circuiting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation)

Comment: What does empirical testing show you when running in a debugger?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Quoting `C11` standard, chapter §6.5.13, *Logical AND operator* (*emphasis mine*)

> Unlike the bitwise binary `&` operator, the `&&` operator guarantees left-to-right evaluation;
>   if the second operand is evaluated, there is a sequence point between the evaluations of
>   the first and second operands. **If the first operand compares equal to 0, the second
>   operand is not evaluated.**

So, if the first condition (LHS operand) evaluates to *false*, the later conditions, i.e., RHS operand of the `&&` is **not** evaluated.

Similarly (*Ironically, rather*), for Logical "OR" operator,

> Unlike the bitwise `|` operator, the `||` operator guarantees left-to-right evaluation; if the
>   second operand is evaluated, there is a sequence point between the evaluations of the first
>   and second operands. **If the first operand compares unequal to 0, the second operand is
>   not evaluated.**

Answer (score 2):

In C both && and || "sort-circuit", meaning if evaluation of the left operand is enough to determine the outcome then the right operand is not evaluated.